# How do I unset category from a product in wordpress by code

Tags: php

I would like to take it out a category from a product. If I want to insert a category I use:

```
$categories = array(1, 2, 3); // Categories IDs
wp_set_post_terms($product->ID, $categories, 'product_cat', true);
```

However I do not know how to unset a category from the product. Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove all category from a WooCommerce product, you can use the wp_set_object_terms() function.

Here is an example of how you can use wp_set_object_terms() to remove categories from a product:

```
// Set the product's categories to an empty array
$categories = array();

wp_set_object_terms( $product->ID, $categories, 'product_cat' );
```

If you want to remove a specific category, you can use the wp_remove_object_terms() function instead. This function allows you to remove specific terms from an object.

Here is an example of how you can use wp_remove_object_terms() to remove a specific category from a product:

```
// Set the category ID to remove
$category_id = 123;

// Remove the category from the product
wp_remove_object_terms( $product->ID, $category_id, 'product_cat' );
```

This code will remove the category with an ID of 123 from the current product

Comment: I tried to use ```wp_remove_object_terms( $product->ID, $category_id, 'product_cat' );```, but the code did not work

Comment: Where do you added the code? in single-product.php ? If so confirm that  `$product->ID` is correct. Or you can try `get_the_ID()` for getting current product_id.

Comment: now it is working, thanks